# Checking Tefillin after someone has died

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilin, mourning-aveilus

Is there a source that one shouldn’t check the deceased Tefillin after they have died?

Comment: Why might you think there is such a source?

Comment: Someone mentioned it but they can’t recall where.

Answer (score 1):

The poskim - see for instance [Rambam Hilchos Tefillin 2(11)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Tefillin%2C_Mezuzah_and_the_Torah_Scroll.2.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) - bring a source (Yerushalmi last perek of Eiruvin - Kesef Mishnah) that Hillel (some say Shammai) used his grandfather's tefillin without needing to check them. That is part of a discussion there whether tefillin need checking in general, or how often. I don't know that it had anything to do with his grandfather dying, just that tefillin, wrapped securely in their batim, don't need frequent checking - others argue.